# A better way to map data in multiple datasets, with multiple data mapping rules

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-mapping

I have three datasets (`final_NN`, `ppt_code`, `herd_id`), and I wish to add a new column called `MapValue` in `final_NN` dataframe, and the value to be added can be retrieved from the other two dataframes, the rule is in the bottom after codes.

```
import pandas as pd

final_NN = pd.DataFrame({
    "number": [123, 456, "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown"],
    "ID": ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 799, 813],
    "code": ["", "", "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "BB", "CC", "", ""]
})

ppt_code = pd.DataFrame({
    "code": ["AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "CC"],
    "number": [11, 11, 22, 22, 33]
})

herd_id = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [799, 813],
    "number": [678, 789]
})

new_column = pd.Series([])
for i in range(len(final_NN)):
    if final_NN["number"][i] != "" and final_NN["number"][i] != "Unknown":
        new_column[i] = final_NN['number'][i]

    elif final_NN["code"][i] != "":
        for p in range(len(ppt_code)):
            if ppt_code["code"][p] == final_NN["code"][i]:
                new_column[i] = ppt_code["number"][p]

    elif final_NN["ID"][i] != "":
        for h in range(len(herd_id)):
            if herd_id["ID"][h] == final_NN["ID"][i]:
                new_column[i] = herd_id["number"][h]

    else:
        new_column[i] = ""

final_NN.insert(3, "MapValue", new_column)
print(final_NN)
```

final_NN:

```
    number   ID code
0      123          
1      456          
2  Unknown        AA
3  Unknown        AA
4  Unknown        BB
5  Unknown        BB
6  Unknown        BB
7  Unknown        CC
8  Unknown  799     
9  Unknown  813
```

ppt_code:

```
  code  number
0   AA      11
1   AA      11
2   BB      22
3   BB      22
4   CC      33
```

herd_id:

```
    ID  number
0  799     678
1  813     789
```

Expected output:

```
    number   ID code   MapValue
0      123                  123
1      456                  456
2  Unknown        AA         11
3  Unknown        AA         11
4  Unknown        BB         22
5  Unknown        BB         22
6  Unknown        BB         22
7  Unknown        CC         33
8  Unknown  799             678
9  Unknown  813             789
```

The rules is:

1. if `number` in final_NN is not `Unknown`, `MapValue` = `number` in `final_NN`;
2. if `number` in final_NN is `Unknown` but `code` in `final_NN` is not Null, then search the ppt_code dataframe, and use the `code` and its corresponding "number" to map and fill in the "MapValue" in `final_NN`;
3. if both `number` and `code` in `final_NN` are `Unknown` and null respectively, but `ID` in `final_NN` is not Null, then search `herd_id` dataframe, and use the `ID` and its corresponding `number` to fill in the `MapValue` in the first dataframe. I applied a loop through the dataframe which is a slow way to achieve this, as above. But I understand there could be a faster way to do this. Just wondering would anyone help me to have a fast and easier way to achieve the same result?

Comment: I think there is no other way

Comment: Thx, but I think there is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a mapping series from the `ppt_code` and `herd_id` dataframes, then use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to create a new column `MapNumber` by replacing the `Unknown` values in `number` column with `np.NaN`, then use two consecutive [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) along with [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to fill the missing values in `MapNumber` column according to the rules:

```
ppt_map = ppt_code.drop_duplicates(subset=['code']).set_index('code')['number']
hrd_map = herd_id.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID']).set_index('ID')['number']

final_NN['MapNumber'] = final_NN['number'].replace({'Unknown': np.nan})
final_NN['MapNumber'] = (
    final_NN['MapNumber']
    .fillna(final_NN['code'].map(ppt_map))
    .fillna(final_NN['ID'].map(hrd_map))
)
```

Result:

```
# print(final_NN)

    number   ID code  MapNumber
0      123                123.0
1      456                456.0
2  Unknown        AA       11.0
3  Unknown        AA       11.0
4  Unknown        BB       22.0
5  Unknown        BB       22.0
6  Unknown        BB       22.0
7  Unknown        CC       33.0
8  Unknown  799           678.0
9  Unknown  813           789.0
```

Comment: Thank you @Shubham Sharma, great answer, Way much faster than the old codes.

Answer (score 0):

We simply combined the three data frames.

1. The original DF removes the 'Unknown' row.
2. 'ppt_code' changes the column names.
3. 'pandas.concat()' joins them together.

```
final_NN['number'].replace('Unknown', np.NaN, inplace=True)
final_NN.dropna(inplace=True, how='any')
ppt_code.rename(columns={'code':'ID'}, inplace=True)
new_df = pd.concat([final_NN, ppt_code, herd_id], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

new_df
    number  ID  code
0   123.0       
1   456.0       
2   11.0    AA  NaN
3   11.0    AA  NaN
4   22.0    BB  NaN
5   22.0    BB  NaN
6   33.0    CC  NaN
7   678.0   799 NaN
8   789.0   813 NaN
```